# Excel INDEX/MATCH with different dates

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to automate our overtime spreadsheet so rather than having people open it up and stick the number of hours next to their name under the column for the correct date (which they often forget to do and we have to chase), it picks it up from the Sharepoint site where we log our overtime.

I thought I had this working with INDEX/MATCH using the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(TEXT(INDEX(Overtime!$H:$H,MATCH($B7,Overtime!$E:$E,0)),"MM")=TEXT("01-"&$B$3&"-"&$B$4,"MM"),IF(F$6=TEXT(INDEX(Overtime!$H:$H,MATCH($B7,Overtime!$E:$E,0)),"DD"),INDEX(Overtime!$J:$J,MATCH($B7,Overtime!$E:$E,0)),""),""),"")
```

This checks for the name in B7, B8 etc against the imported Sharepoint list in sheet "Overtime" and if it matches a name and the month matches the current month (selected from a drop down list in B3) then it returns the number of hours for that person into the current cell.

Each person will have overtime each month, however this just checks for the first occurrence of their name in the Overtime sheet and if the month doesn't match with the current month then nothing is returned. How do I check for a person's name, under the currently selected month, and return the correct value?

Comment: Your formula makes no sense that I can determine; please provide sample data together with expected results and indicate whether something like `Jan` is just `"Jan"` or a date formatted as `mmm`.

Comment: B3 is a full month name, B4 is the year, so I'm creating a date by putting 01-Month-Year and then extracting the month from that, it's probably not the neatest way of doing it.

Comment: That bit works just fine, and I need to do it that way (I think) because in my Overtime sheet I'm comparing to a DD/MM/YYYY format, so I'm pulling out an MM to compare against. That bit works no problems regardless. It's getting it to match against the same name for a different month where I'm struggling. I'm trying to upload an anonymised version of my spreadsheet but my work blocks file sharing sites including Dropbox and OneDrive.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to get this working now: 

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_owssvr_1[#All],MATCH(1,(Overtime!$E:$E=$B7)*(TEXT(Overtime!$H:$H,"mmmm")=$B$3)*(TEXT(Overtime!$H:$H,"DD")=F$6),0),10),"")}

However this is REALLY slow to update, how can I optimise this?